# Algebraic over algebraic is algebraic?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R_1\subseteq R_2\subseteq R_3$ be integral domains. I want to show that if $R_3$ is algebraic over $R_2$ and $R_2$ is algebraic over $R_1$ then $R_3$ is algebraic over $R_1$. [To emphasize: this is algebraic dependence, not necessarily integral dependence.]

My idea is to consider the fields of fractions $K_1:=\mathrm{Frac}(R_1)$, $K_2:=\mathrm{Frac(R_2)}$, $K_3:=\mathrm{Frac}(R_3)$ and then to use the hypotheses to show that $K_3$ is algebraic over $K_1$. By clearing denominators this would imply that $R_3$ is algebraic over $R_1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The result is true. For the full proof along with much more, see the following homework assignment and solutions:
http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/762sp16/762hw3sol.pdf

The relevant theorem is Problem 4(d).

Comment: I don't understand where you are stuck - you seem to have given the entire argument. Once you know that $K_3$ is algebraic over $K_1$, then for any element in $K_3$ you can get an algebraic equation for it over $K_1$. Then, as you say, clear the denominators in this equation to make the coefficients in $R_1$. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I'm stuck trying to show that $K_3$ is algebraic over $K_1$.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. You want to show this: If a domain $R$ is an algebraic extension of $L$, then $Frac(R)$ is algebraic over $Frac(L)$? You can pick a generating set for $Frac(R)$ (as a field) which consists of elements in $R$. If a field extension is generated by algebraic elements, it is algebraic. (Again this is a game with replacing algebraic with the condition that the field generated by the element is finite dimensional as a vector space over the base.)

Comment: HINT: if $A,B$ are two domains, then $A \subset B$ is algebraic if and only if $\operatorname{Frac}(A) \subset \operatorname{Frac}(B)$ is algebraic.

Comment: Algebraic / algebraic is Rational function.

Comment: @Crostul I don't understand why $\mathrm{Frac}(A)\subseteq\mathrm{Frac}(B)$ algebraic implies that $A\subseteq B$ is algebraic.

Comment: @DrewArmstrong For all $b \in B$, $b \in \operatorname{Frac}(B)$, so that there exists $f \in \operatorname{Frac}(A)[X]$ such that $f(b)=0$. Now, multiply $f$ by all denominators of its coefficients and you will get some polynomial $g \in A[x]$ such that $g(b)=0$.